# Using treesitter on neovim to highlight html closing tag

Tags: neovim, neovim-plugin, treesitter

When using neovim, if you place the cursor on an opening bracket, it will highlight the closing one.

[image]

Is it possible to highlight the closing html tag when placing the cursor on an opening html tag using treesitter?

[image]

like in this screenshot

[image]